# In Perl, how do you create a reference to the output of a subroutine without using an intermediate variable?

Tags: perl, reference

Suppose I have a list called `@emailList`, and I would like to pass a reference to that list to a subroutine called `sendEmail`.  I know I can do it this way:

```
my @emailList = split(/[$EMAIL_DELIMS]+/, $emailListStr);
sendEmail(\@emailList);
```

But if I want to create a reference to the output of split directly without using the intermediate variable `@emailList`, what's the correct syntax?  I have already tried:

```
sendEmail(\@{split(/[$EMAIL_DELIMS]+/, $emailListStr)});
```

… as well as many subtle variations of this, but `perl` always complains. Suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
sendEmail([ split(/[$EMAIL_DELIMS]+/, $emailListStr) ]);
```

will create an anonymous array populated using the list returned by `split` and pass it to `sendEmail`.

Also, you might want to use [`Email::Address->parse`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Email%3a%3aAddress).

Comment: Though touched on, you should look into and understand the difference between contexts (scalar and list) and variables (scalar, array and hash), as that's going to let you know exactly why this works.

Comment: The real difference that needs understanding is the difference between a "list" and an "array". You cannot have a list "named" anything, lists are not "nameable". Mansoor has an _array_ named @emailList the _value_ in that array is a "list".